# Where can I download Scala source jars (scala-library-src.jar etc.)

Tags: scala

I am trying to use IntelliJ Idea Scala plugin, but it says it wants scala-library-src.jar, scala-swing-src.jar, scala-dbc-src.jar. Where can I download these files? I use Scala 2.8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get them from the Scala Maven repo at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/scala-tools/.

In particular, https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/scala-tools/org/scala-lang/ has all the Scala library jars.

Comment: Any suggestions on how one can find the above mentioned `.jar`'s using these links or `mvn` command? I am looking to download `scala-library-src.jar`

Answer (score -2):

Go to http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/ and find the version you want that ends in .zip.  Get that and extract it.

If you get the msi file then it doesn't install the src dir, but the zip does contain src.

Comment: does not include the src jars