# Facing issue while trying to enable source code in IntelliJ for scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am new to Scala programming and I have just started with basic programs in scala in IntelliJ IDE.

When i use the below code

package com.allaboutscala.chapter.one.tutorial_04

object HelloWorld extends App{
  println("hello from hello world")

}

I wanted to see the source code of App where it uses the main method, but when i tries to see the source code and when I try to download it, I am getting error like 
Sources not found: Sources for 'scala-library.jar' not found. I have attached the screenshot also.It would be great if someone could guide me here.

[image]

Comment: Where is the screenshot?

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739193/where-can-i-download-scala-source-jars-scala-library-src-jar-etc

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using sbt, you need to enable downloading of sources for your project:

1. open IntelliJ Preferences
2. search "sbt" or navigate to Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | sbt
3. select "Download: library sources"
4. refresh the sbt project